# CSS Transform not working in IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-transforms

I've exhausted every resource on this I can find and cannot find a solution. I am trying to animate opacity and the Y coordinate for a graphic with IE 11 as the browser.

Opacity works fine (the graphic fades in and out) in IE 11, transform does not work in IE 11. In Firefox, both work.

Here is the CSS:

```
@keyframes 
pulse
{
 0%
 {
   opacity: 1.0;   
   transform: translateY(+5px);
 }
 45%
 {
   opacity: .20;
   transform: translateY(-5px);         
 }
 100%
 {
   opacity: 1.0;
   transform: translateY(+5px);          
 }
}
#blink_layer {  
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: pulse;
   }
```

I know TRANSFORM is supported in IE 11 and does not require any prefix.

How can I get TRANSFORM to work in IE? What might be breaking transform here?

Comment: Transforms don't work on SVG's in IE11 - what are you transforming?  Additionally, no need for `+5px` - just use `5px`

Comment: the api places it inside a <g> tag. I guess that means it is SVG? the image itself is PNG

Comment: Yep, that's an SVG.  IE11 won't transform it, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)